# How do I populate Google Map annotations from MVC model

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, model-view-controller

I am making good progress using a Google Map.

The example I am following uses a hard coded JSON array to create annotations

```
// You can make markers different colors...  google it up!
marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')

// a sample list of JSON encoded data of places to visit in Liverpool, UK
// you can either make up a JSON list server side, or call it from a controller using JSONResult
var data = [
          { "Id": 1, "PlaceName": "Liverpool Museum", "OpeningHours":"9-5, M-F","GeoLong": "53.410146", "GeoLat": "-2.979919" },
          { "Id": 2, "PlaceName": "Merseyside Maritime Museum ", "OpeningHours": "9-1,2-5, M-F", "GeoLong": "53.401217", "GeoLat": "-2.993052" },
          { "Id": 3, "PlaceName": "Walker Art Gallery", "OpeningHours": "9-7, M-F", "GeoLong": "53.409839", "GeoLat": "-2.979447" },
          { "Id": 4, "PlaceName": "National Conservation Centre", "OpeningHours": "10-6, M-F", "GeoLong": "53.407511", "GeoLat": "-2.984683" }
       ];

// Using the JQuery "each" selector to iterate through the JSON list and drop marker pins
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLong, item.GeoLat),
        'map': map,
        'title': item.PlaceName
    });
```

However, I am new to MVC.  Please can someone clarify the 2 approaches mentioned in the comment?  I have all the points in a list of C# objects.  This list is in my model object for the page.  AlertsDashboardModel which contains a list - Alerts

I would probably use the list in the model directly, but I am curious how the other approach would work

I am using MVC 5 with Razor

Paul

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/jmelosegui/GooglemapMvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is alluding to loading the data once the page has loaded (or as a result of a user interaction on the page like pressing a button) which then sends an ajax request to the server which returns the data:

Client:

```
$(function () {
    //fetch data points from server on page load
    $.get("/YourController/GetDataPoints", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        //rest omitted
    });
}
```

Server: (in your `Controller`)

```
public JsonResult GetDataPoints()
{
    return new JsonResult { Data = ...your list here };
}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to do just the first method of embedded the list as javascript on the server side do this in your razor view:

```
<script>
        var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.DataPoints));
</script>
```

**Regarding security** you need to ensure that everything in that list comes from a trusted source and there is no unvalidated strings that could get injected into the page (if your data point class contains just `int` you will be fine)

Comment: Thanks that almost worked, I just needed to add JsonRequestBehaviour.  Could you help with how to do the first approach please?  I.e. server side list.  I was hoping to just be able to bind to my property on the model but it appears as though its not that simple!  I am also wondering if this way is a good way because of the security aspect of it